# Future Malazan novels by Steven Erikson?

Tags: malazan, steven-erikson

Does anybody have any idea of what are Steven Erikson's plans towards works set in the Malazan world? Can we expect more of Ganeos and others? Also, I believe that Erikson and Esslemont have a pact about not interfering with each other, is that true?

Comment: worth mentioning that the first of the two trilogies planned has been put on hold after book 2 and Erikson is now working on the second trilogy instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a [forum discussion following a signing tour](http://www.sffworld.com/forums/showthread.php?t=20236) (so second hand info)

> Steven Erikson confirmed that he has
>   signed up for 6 more Malazan novels
>   for Bantam. They will not be direct
>   continuations of the Malazan Book of
>   the Fallen, but will be two somewhat
>   self-contained trilogies, one of which
>   will be the backstory of Anomander
>   Rake. He also confirmed that the two
>   new trilogies will be released at a
>   more leisurely pace than the MBF, as
>   the one-book-per-year pace is too much
>   to keep up indefinitely.
>
> He also confirmed that there are 6
>   more Bauchelain and Korbal Broach
>   novellas to come, to bring the total
>   to 9.
>
> Added in with the 10 volumes of the
>   MBF itself and Esslemont's planned 6
>   novels, that brings the total to 22
>   novels, 9 novellas and 1 companion
>   volume set in this world.

Answer (score 3):

From [wiki page of Steven Erikson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Erikson) :

> During a 2008 question and answer session in Seattle, Washington, Erikson stated he had signed a deal to write two more trilogies and six novellas; Erikson planned to use the novellas to continue the Bauchelain and Korbal Broach storyline while one of the trilogies would be a prequel to the main series, detailing the history of Anomander Rake and Mother Dark.

From [an interview at The Void](http://the-void.co.uk/book/interview-damn-contrarian-steven-erikson-conversation-094)

> Q:Is it correct that your next project is a prequel trilogy about Anomander Rake? What’s the plan? And will there be further spin-off series? You’ve written away from the series. Do you envisage ever ending it permanently?
>
> A:It took me a month to think about
>   writing after completing The Crippled
>   God. That’s the longest break I’ve had
>   since I first started writing
>   full-time. It was vaguely alarming. In
>   thinking about it and in writing it,
>   The Malazan Book of the Fallen
>   consumed more than twenty years of my
>   life, day after day, night after
>   night. And suddenly… nothing. I felt
>   (and still feel) I could drop dead
>   tomorrow, and apart from some regret
>   over those who would be saddened at my
>   passing, I’d be pretty fine with that.
>   I did what I wanted to do, said what I
>   wanted and needed to say, completed my
>   modest salute to Homer and The Iliad,
>   and all that.
>
> Eventually, things started stirring
>   again (keep your thoughts out of my
>   trousers!), and I started thinking
>   about another modest salute, this time
>   to The Bard himself, and from that
>   impetus some notes started taking
>   shape, and the new trilogy was
>   underway.
>
> Obviously, I won’t give much away,
>   only to say that it’s tighter, not
>   quite so sprawling, not so wide-angled
>   in focus, and that structurally it’s
>   looking far more… traditional. Who’da
>   thunk, eh?

Answer (score 1):

As of March 19th, 2019 Steven Erikson is working on the Witness trilogy which is based around Karsa Orlong. The first book is almost done.  More info in [this blog post](https://steven-erikson.org/life-on-thin-ice-updating-my-progress-on-the-witness-trilogy/).